# Should I trim white space from SQL statements before executing them?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am in the habit of using a stringbuilder to build up an Sql statement to execute, as this allows me to keep the statement formatted and readable in the code.  However it can produce an inefficient statement with lots of extra whitespace:

```
sb.AppendLine (@"SELECT DISTINCT *");
sb.AppendLine (@"    FROM (  SELECT col1");
sb.AppendLine (@"                 ,  col2");
sb.AppendLine (@"                 ,  col3 ");
sb.AppendLine (@"                 ,  col4");
sb.AppendLine (@"              FROM (SELECT *");
sb.AppendLine (@"                      FROM TABLE )";
sb.AppendLine (@"             WHERE col5= col1 ");
sb.AppendLine (@"             AND col6 = col2 ");
sb.AppendLine (@"          GROUP BY col1");
sb.AppendLine (@"                 ,  col2");
sb.AppendLine (@" ORDER BY col3");
```

this sql is an example of the issue and may not even be correct.

Should I strip the whitespace from this before I pass it to to a command object to be executed?  Or will the command do this itself, or is this just a micro optimization which is not worth thinking about?

Comment: I don't think there is a measurable difference.

Comment: @juergend - That depends on a lot of factors.  What if your server is being hit with 100's of queries a second?  I bet it becomes measurable then.  *[And yes, this does happen in real time environments.  And no, I doubt it applies here ;)]*

Comment: *cough* stored procedures *cough*

Comment: Keep in mind that parsed statements can be cached based on the sql string (Oracle's sql cache, JDBC statement caching on connection pools), so you should at least be consistent (build the statement string only once, use binds).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I declare my SQL queries in the code:

```
string query = @"
    select columns
    from table
    where condition = 1
";
```

Here are the pros:

- Way better readability, no clutter
- I can easily copy the SQL block to/from a SQL client tool
- A version control diff tool will easily show me what has changed in the query only.

No cons so far :)

**Update**

Oh, and, yes, I think worrying about extra white spaces is over-optimization.

Comment: cons - even more whitespace :)

Comment: @SamHolder That would be true (being a con) **IF** having whites spaces will have any impact in performance. I'd say it would **very rarely** have any *substantial impact*. Before you even got to that, you should have found **many** other bottlenecks in your application. You are micro worrying. Seriously, you would gain more by making your code more readable :)

Comment: yeah I'm with you @Adrian seems like an unecessary step to me, but it came up in a code review the other day so I wanted to see what the wider community thought.  I think I'll switch to your string literal style for the sql though.  thanks.

Comment: @SamHolder I bet appending strings using a StringBuilder is way slower than this.

Answer (score 2):

As you already stated, I think you're over-optimizing.  You're talking maybe 100 bytes.  You're result set will probably be larger than that.